# PWA Setup in Magento 2.3.0 on Windows 7

Tags: magento2, windows, pwa, pwa-studio

what I have:

- OS Windows 7
- PHP Version 7.1.22
- NodeJS 10.14.2
- Yarn 1.13.0

I use instruction from 
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/
and
https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

So, what I did:

- installed fresh magento 2.3 from composer via `command composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.3.0 f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\`
- cloned pwa-studio (`git clone https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git`) into magento instance: `f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\pwa-studio`
- `cd pwa-studio` and run `yarn install`
- set `MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="http://m2pwa2.local/"` in `f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\pwa-studio\packages\venia-concept\.env`
- installed sample data of venia-theme

When I go to `f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\pwa-studio\` and run `yarn run build` I see:

```
f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\pwa-studio>node -v
v10.14.2

f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\pwa-studio>yarn -v
1.13.0

f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\pwa-studio>yarn run build
yarn run v1.13.0
$ yarn workspaces run build
$ concurrently --raw yarn:build:cjs yarn:build:esm
$ BABEL_ENV=production babel src --out-dir dist --root-mode 'upward' --source-ma
ps
$ BABEL_ENV=development babel src --out-dir esm --root-mode 'upward' --source-ma
ps
'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this comm
and.
'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this comm
and.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this comm
and.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Arguments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js build
Directory: f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\pwa-studio\packages\peregrine
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspaces for documentation about th
is command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this comm
and.

f:\OSPanel\domains\m2pwa2.local\pwa-studio>
```

[image]

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: yes i am also getting same error have gone through all methods still no success..let me know if anyone find the solution
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rGmM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rGmM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because windows does not support Magento PWA studio. Please use Linux subsystem for windows to install it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share a guide to install everything from scratch including subsystem OS and PHP, MySQL, magento2, react, redux, python and everything. So that beginners can start with it too.

Comment: Hi,  

Use magento official guide to install pwa studio.

PWA studio official guide : https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

Install linux subsystem on windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Use Xampp for PHP with 7.2.11

Comment: Yes. I tried but It is also showing me a URL, but it is not rendering anything.

Comment: Can you please check this error? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/271144/pwa-studio-yarn-build-error

Comment: Yes, you're right. I installed Vagrant + Virtualbox, then Magento 2.3.1... And PWA studio started successfully.

Comment: @PHPer Vagrant + Virtualbox install then pwa works on windows?can you explain

Comment: I disagree on statement "windows does not support Magento PWA studio", there might be complications but "does not support" does not seems correct statement to me.

Comment: @kapil yadav : I think you misunderstood what I said, Magento do not support means that there are some known complications which Magento team already know but they are not priorities and Magento team not planning to fix them. It doesn't mean that pwa is un installable on window plateform. Even if you are using EE edition, Magento team will not fix your plateform related issue. If you have seen Magento official documents , it has linux & mac but not windows. If you still feel disagreement, please share you point of view.

Answer (score 0):

@Nadh

Step 1. you need to install Vagrant + VirtualBox on windows

Step 2. you need to install Ubuntu into Vagrant. I use https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-18.04

Step 3. Install Apache + PHP + MySQL into Ubunto: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-install-apache-php-7-1-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-vagrant/

Step 4. Install Magento 2.3.x (without sample data) https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

Step 5. Add Venia sample data https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/install-sample-data/

Step 6. Clone the PWA Studio repository

Step 7. Run PWA into Vagrant and Ubunto

So, you don't need to use windows. Everything will works into Vagrant + Ubunto on your windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for answer.How to install Vagrant and Virtualbox?

Comment: https://www.taniarascia.com/what-are-vagrant-and-virtualbox-and-how-do-i-use-them/

Comment: step2 not understanding

Comment: need to install webpack,graphql as well and if any please explain