# Pwa studio yarn build error

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa-studio, graphql

> ⚠ GraphQL Error (Code: 404): {"response":{"error":"\n\n404 Not
>   Found\n\n
>
> ## Not Found
>
> \n
>
> The requested URL
>   /graphql was not found on this
>   server.
>
> \n
>
> ---
>
> \nApache/2.4.33 (Win32) PHP/7.2.4 Server at
>   192.168.1.105 Port 80\n\n","status":404},"request":{"query":"\n
>   query IntrospectionQuery {\n      __schema {\n        queryType { name
>   }\n        mutationType { name }\n        subscriptionType { name }\n 
>   types {\n          ...FullType\n        }\n        directives {\n
>   name\n          description\n          locations\n          args {\n
>   ...InputValue\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n\n    fragment
>   FullType on __Type {\n      kind\n      name\n      description\n
>   fields(includeDeprecated: true) {\n        name\n        description\n
>   args {\n          ...InputValue\n        }\n        type {\n
>   ...TypeRef\n        }\n        isDeprecated\n
>   deprecationReason\n      }\n      inputFields {\n
>   ...InputValue\n      }\n      interfaces {\n        ...TypeRef\n
>   }\n      enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {\n        name\n
>   description\n        isDeprecated\n        deprecationReason\n
>   }\n      possibleTypes {\n        ...TypeRef\n      }\n    }\n\n
>   fragment InputValue on __InputValue {\n      name\n      description\n
>   type { ...TypeRef }\n      defaultValue\n    }\n\n    fragment TypeRef
>   on __Type {\n      kind\n      name\n      ofType {\n        kind\n
>   name\n        ofType {\n          kind\n          name\n
>   ofType {\n            kind\n            name\n            ofType {\n
>   kind\n              name\n              ofType {\n
>   kind\n                name\n                ofType {\n
>   kind\n                  name\n                  ofType {\n
>   kind\n                    name\n                  }\n
>   }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n
>   }\n  "}}

**Please check screenshots:**

1. http://prntscr.com/nfx29r
2. http://prntscr.com/nfx35i
3. http://prntscr.com/nfx3ez

Answer (score 0):

you can change the **/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/.env** file

**Put Example (Run) URL in .env**

**Example:**

**MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://release-dev-231-npzdaky-zddsyhrdimyra.us-4.magentosite.cloud/**

*If this url run then issue in your MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL*